# Error when extracting data from firebase into flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to ask for some help or advice.
I have a simple form which stores data in Firebase.
I created a new page where I want to display that information. I am using `StreamBuilder` to display the data for the logged user.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Your upcoming appointments"),
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('client_bookings_doc').where('email', isEqualTo: currentUser.currentUser!.email).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                  print(data['email']);
                  return Text(data['email']);
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const Text("error");
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I don't understand why I am getting that error:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3777): .................. requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
> E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 3777): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
> W/Firestore( 3777): (24.4.2) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException

I was following a few tutorials online and they both work fine.
Any help will be appreciated.

---

Update: I changed the device to google pixel 2 and now the error is

> W/ProviderInstaller( 5334): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]

[image: firestore document picture :]

Comment: Would you please share the firestore document picture with us?

Comment: comment is updated now

Answer (score 1):

This query doesn't match the document structure in your screenshot:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('client_bookings_doc')
  .where('email', isEqualTo: currentUser.currentUser!.email)
  .snapshots()
```

There is no **collection** `client_bookings_doc` in your screenshot. Instead there is a root collection `client_bookings` with a **document** `client_bookings_doc` and then a subcollection again named `client_bookings`.

If you want to query across all `client_bookings` collection, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collectionGroup('client_bookings') // 
  .where('email', isEqualTo: currentUser.currentUser!.email)
  .snapshots()
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my query now, however i still got that eorro: W/DynamiteModule(12066): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(12066): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(12066): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.